# Session Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring

my question is about
how can i add a session to

my problem is: when im registering and immadietly from "/" go to /user/aboutme/1 its working but when i go to /user, its impossible for me, i think i need to add session to my loginController but how, can u help me?? please 
[https://github.com/PatrykBrzuchacz/SpringProjekt-master3

```
@GetMapping("/login")
public String login(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("title", title);
    return "user/login";
}
```

Comment: Sessions do not belong in the controller

Comment: i know, its just a start but can u explain me how it should look?

Comment: What security pattern you have in your xml?

Comment: check in github please, there are everything

Answer (score 0):

These are code pieces you may find useful. Be more precise to get precise answer.

You can access the session object this way:

```
@GetMapping("/login")
public String login(Model model, HttpSession session) {

}
```

If you want to have something in your url use path variables:

```
@GetMapping("/something/{user}")
public String login(@PathVariable("user") String user) {

}
```

If you want to secure access you may want to use `@PreAuthorize` but this is only one of the options.